# Careers messages target="_blank" breaking HTML?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Something funky is happening with the way URLs are parsed on the Careers site for applications.

Normal URLs such as `<a href="//example.com">Foo</a>` parse correctly and act as a hyperlink that renders as the text `Foo`. However, the same link with a `target="_blank"` in the element such as:

`<a target="_blank" href="//example.com/>Foo</a>` renders as `example.com" target="_blank">foo`

Also, the raw HTML sent is:

`<a href="&lt;a href=" http:="" //example.com="" "="" rel="nofollow">Foo</a>" target="_blank"&gt;<a href="//example.com" rel="nofollow">Foo</a></div>`

It looks like whatever is parsing the `<a>` tags just didn't anticipate other attributes in the element, so complex attributes get treated as raw URLs. I have an application in my inbox *full* of these broken links from someone on Feb 13th who's email has an md5 hash `0e17213e867e2801be836c6b41674cc7` (I don't want to post stuff publicly).

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a bug, looking into it.

Comment: Is that missing fourth double-quote in the target-blank example part of the bug or a typo?

Comment: @Bobby I've added an image to the Q with censored URLs. This issue exists over multiple applications received, and one that I've personally sent (and I'm confident I did not goof up with the WYSIWYG editor)

Comment: [That wasn't my question.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RHQZa.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug and has been fixed.  Thanks for the report.

Comment: Thank you so much, the applications look so much cleaner now.